# Video element for XHTML MP - WAP2 Phones

Tags: video, xhtml, wap

I am trying to develop a XHTML MP website supporting for wap2 browsers.

Video elememt in html5 is not working and also I tried object element. Both of them are not supported . I tried to play in a nokia 220 Phone. but nothing is coming.

sample Code used

```
<video controls="controls" poster="" width="200" height="200">
        <source src="video/small.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://flashfox.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/flashfox.swf" id="video-elemnt" >
            <param name="movie" value="http://flashfox.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/flashfox.swf" />
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
            <param name="flashVars" value="controls=true&amp;poster=&amp;src=video/small.3gp" />
            <img alt="" src="video/small.mp4" width="250" height="200" title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
        </object>
    </video>
```

I also tried object method - sample code

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://flashfox.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/flashfox.swf" width="200" height="200">
                <param name="movie" value="http://flashfox.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/flashfox.swf" />
                <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
                <param name="flashVars" value="controls=true&amp;poster=&amp;src=video/small.mp4" />
                <img alt="" src="video/small.mp4" id="video-elemnt" title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
            </object>
```

can anyone Please help with this. 
Which element I should use for playing a video in wap2 browser.

Comment: I honestly don't know why this was downvoted.

Comment: I also tried using '<embed src="video/test2.mpg" width="320" height="200" autostart="false" loop="3"/>' thia but not working. Can anyone please help with this.